# IPython Notebook crashing Chrome tabs

Tags: google-chrome, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm doing some work in an IPython Notebook session, and I now have a large-ish notebook containing code, some plots, and some embedded videos (of plot stacks; it seemed like the easiest way to be able to scroll through a sequence of plots interactively in the Notebook view). I'm working in Chrome (Mac, 32.0.1700.102) since H.264 encoding worked best (Vp8 compressed out shading detail in the plots that I needed), and Safari and Firefox don't render the videos.

Recently, this notebook has started crashing Chrome tabs every couple minutes (showing the 'Aw Snap' page). It's become basically unusable. I can work, saving very frequently, but saving the notebook causes the Chrome tab to crash about half the time (which makes me wonder if the random crashes that occur when I'm working are caused by the autosaves, but I don't know).

Has anyone else encountered this? Does anyone know how to fix it? Is there some more information I can provide to diagnose the problem? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in 32-bit Chrome on my Windows 8.1 Enterprise PC. Chrome often crashed while running a large jupyter notebook (~100 MB on disk). It got a bit better after upgrading my chrome to the 64 bit version. However, jupyter still complained about the size of the notebooks, crashed once in a while, and my notebooks could not be saved. This issue was discussed here:

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/650

The quick fix proposed here was to increase the value for self.max_buffer_size in env/Lib/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py (line 154, in case of version 4.4.2 of tornado). I changed the value x10, and now a notebook larger than 130 MB runs without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue. Actually I found this is related to chrome extensions installed.

Try disabling all the extensions and re-enabling them one by one. You'll find which is crashing your tab. In my case, crashes were due to the Evernote extension.

Alternatively, you can open up an incognito window, which has all the extensions disabled by default, and try opening your notebook there.

Ciao